# Entity Framework Delete Entity without its Dependency

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While I am trying to delete my entity I am getting following error in my function;

> A relationship from the 'ProjectWebsiteTag_ProjectUser' AssociationSet is
>   in the 'Deleted' state. 
>       Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'ProjectWebsiteTag_ProjectUser_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

Here is my code to delete;

```
public bool Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ProjectDataContext context = new ProjectDataContext())
                {

                    ProjectWebsiteTag websiteTag = context.WebsiteTags.FirstOrDefault(p => p.WebsiteTagId == id);
                    context.WebsiteTags.Remove(websiteTag);
                    int saveChanges = context.SaveChanges();
                    return saveChanges > 0;
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                FormattedDbEntityValidationException newException = new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(e);
                throw newException;
            }
        }
```

Here is my data class;

```
public class ProjectWebsiteTag
    {
        public int WebsiteTagId { get; set; }
        public ProjectUser ProjectUser { get; set; }
        public ProjectWebsite ProjectWebsite { get; set; }           
    }
```

My Config Class;

```
 public ProjectWebsiteTagConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("ProjectWebsiteTags");
            HasKey(p => p.WebsiteTagId);
            HasRequired(p => p.ProjectUser).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasRequired(p => p.ProjectWebsite).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

It looks like it is trying to delete User record, but I do not want that.
I just want to delete "ProjectWebsiteTag" and that's it.

What I am missing here?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a case of cascade deleting, it's trying to ADD a user with null values in non-nullable fields

Comment: @Rob Why it would even do that? I am not even intending to pull user entity from context.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't trying to delete the ProjectUser. It's trying to insert it. ProjectWebsiteTagConfiguration() is saying that the ProjectWebsiteTags table has a ProjectUser foreign key in it. When you call

```
ProjectWebsiteTag websiteTag = context.WebsiteTags.FirstOrDefault(p => p.WebsiteTagId == id)
```

websiteTag has a ProjectUser with an empty string for its UserId property. So either the record in the ProjectWebsiteTags table has an empty string for the foreign key, or EF is newing a ProjectUser (with an empty UserId) when you get from the context. Either way, EF isn't aware of the existence of a ProjectUser with an empty string id, so when you call SaveChanges() it tries to add it. It can't because the UserId field is required and empty.

Comment: You're right. I was initializing User object inside ProjectWebsiteTag  constructor. I removed that initialization. Meanwhile, I am getting different error now. I updated the question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix my problem by adding one-to-many relationship configuration in my User class.
It comes to a resolution of I need to add relationship hint on both sides of Configuration declarations.

```
public class ProjectUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectUser>
    {
        public ProjectUserConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("ProjectUsers");
            HasKey(p => p.UserId);
            HasMany(p=>p.ProjectWebsiteTags).WithRequired(q=>q.ProjectUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```